# bundler error when deploying to production with capistrano

Tags: ruby, capistrano, bundler, digital-ocean, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm trying to get my rails app (created by DigitalOcen one click installer) to up and running, but I'm keep on getting this error in `unicorn.log`

`You have already activated kgio 2.8.1, but your Gemfile requires kgio 2.9.2. Prepending`bundle exec`to your command may solve this.`

I have the `rake-10.3.2` in both my local can the server. 
I have the same `kgio-2.9.2` in both my local and the server.

and since my `cap deploy` runs without a problem, I'm not sure where to add the `bundle exec` as it suggest in the error message

server ruby version `ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux]`
local machine version `ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]`
`Rails 4.1.1` is same in both local and the server and
`capistrano-2.15.5`

any help would be appreciated :)